# Prove that product of n consecutive numbers is divisible by n!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, factorial

Prove that product of n consecutive numbers is divisible by n!
That is, 
 If $ P = (a) (a+1)...(a + n -1)$ 
Then, 
$n!|P$

Prove it in two ways, one without induction and another with induction.

I tried to prove it with the help of Euclid Division Algorithm first because when I had countable terms like 3 terms of the form $(a)(a+1)(a+2)$ O could use it to prove that it was divisible by 6 or 3!.
But I could not get anywhere.

Then I looked in the book which uses the principle of mathematical induction, which I think didn't used Induction correctly (pic attached)

~Thanks

Links to the book pages https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJjHU.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vwf3.jpg

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: hmm... you are not supposed to give us assignments to do. are you stucked?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: This is not assignment, I just read the proof in a book but I am not satisfied with it, you can hint me if you don't want to answer completely ~ thanks

Comment: Ok I'll edit my question @5xum

Comment: I have seen this question about a week ago on the same site. So I think it should be removed, as it is a duplicate. I am also relatively new to the site, so I am not sure how to look for the other post efficiently.

Comment: Note that any proof of a non-trivial statement true for all integers will conceal an induction somewhere.

Comment: @Mark Bennet, can you please explain a little bit more about that.  ~thanks

Comment: Well, if you take the Peano postulates for the positive integers the only way of proving anything about all integers is to use induction. So, for example, to prove that of any two successive numbers one is even and one is odd, requires an induction in the background, though it might easily be assumed as a "fact of arithmetic". Here you should need two, because your result is true for all $n$ and for all $a$. I think even if you assume associative, commutative and distributive laws for addition and multiplication (which you have to prove if you take Peano as a base) you still need induction.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you think is wrong with the book's proof?  (It looks OK to me.)

Comment: @awkward Yeah, now I understood where I went wrong, I had a understanding mistake. ~ Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint.

What is it $\binom{a+n-1}{n}$?